# excel error 1004 autofilter method of range class failed

Tags: vba, excel-2016

I am trying to use the autofilter method in a macro for some reason excel fails when calling the autofilter method. I get excel error 1004 autofilter method of range class failed. This is the line where it fails

```
Range("S2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(0, "1/0/1900")
```

This is already a changed version originally my code looked like this but I got the same error.

```
 ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$W$" & Rows.Count).AutoFilter Field:=19, Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(0, "1/0/1900")
```

I tried this aswell but it also didn't work

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A:W").AutoFilter Field:=19, Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(0, "1/0/1900")
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is an English speaking community - you should update your question to be written in English - otherwise your question will be closed.

Comment: Most likely because "1/0/1900" is no valid date ...

Answer (score 0):

To the comment telling me the date is not valid. I am pretty sure it is. Thats how the date is entered in the worksheet I got from my coworker
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1fDP.png

That's German Date Format but it is the same as 1/0/1990. I can not show more of the table cause of company rules

Comment: Actually the wrong date was the problem. I entered a different date on the same year that is valid because I am only filtering on year level anyway now it is working

Comment: Please don't use an answer as a comment. You should delete this answer and update/edit your question instead.    .....  1/0/1990 isn't a valid date in neither date format.